# How to batch execute with JOOQ

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, jdbc, jooq

I'm calling existing MySql stored procedures using JOOQ. My code is in Java. Everything is ok but i'm a bit confused when it comes to batch inserts. For example, i have simple like this:

```
private void executeBatch(DSLContext context, LinkedList<AbstractRoutine<Void>> procedures) {
        BatchBindStep step = null;
        for (AbstractRoutine<Void> procedure : procedures) {
            step = context.batch (context.select(procedure.asField()));
        }

        step.execute();
    }
```

Each and every procedure from supplied LinkedList is an update or insert procedure with it's own arguments set and is actually ready for execution. I'm just trying to bind them together for batch processing.

When i try execute code above, i'm getting error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Can not issue SELECT via executeUpdate().
```

What am i doing wrong? What should i fix? I was trying to search for an answer online but seems like using JOOQ both batch stored procedure calls isn't so popular. I have to do it in order to keep compatibility with rest of my pre-JOOQ application....

Comment: For the record, this was also asked on the user group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/o0Zd9rKoxlg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed with Lukas Eder in said Google group, this feature (batch calling stored procedures) will be added to JOOQ 3.11.

Answer (score 2):

[As discussed on the user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/o0Zd9rKoxlg), there is currently (as of jOOQ 3.10) no out-of-the-box support in jOOQ for batching stored procedures. The pending feature request is here:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6813

#### Workarounds

There are various workarounds for your specific use-case, including:

- Using a staging table and loading data / parameter sets in there.
- Loading data directly into the target table using jOOQ's [batching API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/) or [data loading API](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing/)
- Using table valued parameters if your database supports that
- Bypassing jOOQ and resorting to plain JDBC

Answer (score 0):

Your stored procedures must no execute any result that can be reached as output from Java, because each procedure is called using `executeUpdate` function.

*From Java documentation*:

> int executeUpdate(String sql) throws SQLException
>
> Executes the given SQL statement, which may be an INSERT,
> UPDATE, or DELETE statement or an SQL statement that returns nothing,
> such as an SQL DDL statement.